# Ajax/Php - Real Time Online User Counter

Tags: php, ajax, counter

I want to have an Online user counter but something which performs **real time**. I mean when someone comes in, the counter updates, or when someone leaves the site, the counter decrease.

I can't find anything like this on net. Is there any script for this ?

Comment: Here is exactly what you need (for wordpress only): http://codecanyon.net/item/realtime-online-users/3740135

Comment: I would suggest your accepted answer doesn't answer your question.  It is not real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably keep a list of all sessions in a database and update the "online time" every time someone hits a page. Then check how many sessions were updated in the last x minutes. However, this won't be very real time: depending on the amount of minutes you defined it will be a little bit off.

Even Google Analytics (the new real time version) gets it wrong sometimes. Don't worry too much if you can't get it right either. ;-)

Comment: Google analytics doesn't do real-time connections because it's resource intensive and isn't necessary for what they are trying to track.  It is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look to `WebSocket`. There is a lot of demos out there, mostly real-time chat application, you could hack something on it :)
In my opinion, `WebSocket` seems a bit overhead in you case (you just want a number, no real two-sides communications) but it's the good way to do "real-time" apps.

Here are some links:

- [Socket.IO](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO) (node.js backend)
- [WebSocket and Socket.IO](http://davidwalsh.name/websocket)
- [Introduction to Server-Sent Events](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/10/19/introduction-to-server-sent-events/) (another technique)
- [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/)

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know there is no way to track when a user leaves your site, short of a log out button (which one can easily avoid by simply closing the window)

Comment: You could probably hack something together with the window's `unload` event.

Comment: The browser fires the unload event when a user navigates away from the page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Tom's answer, you could create a table that tracks sessions in a database. At minimum the fields should be session_id, ip_address, activity_time. Name them whatever you'd like. You would need a function that executes on every page load that matches a record on session_id and ip_address. If a matching record does not exist, you create one; if a match is made, then update the time.

A few caveats:

1) getting the right ip address can be tricky, especially with AOL users and/or proxy users. You need to look for X_Forwarded_For headers. If they exist, for a user, use that address, otherwise use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. I would suggest looking up X_Forwarded_For for your setup because Im not sure its available for all setups

1a) if you dont get the right ip address, some users will create a new entry on every page view

2) You need a way to remove stale sessions. I suggest as part of the function that updates the activity time, it also checks for any activity_time that is older than 5 minutes (I use 15 minutes) and if so, removes the corresponding record.

Then all you need to do is a simple count on the table and that will give you a reasonably accurate representation of the number of users currently online. With very little coding you could put this to a lot of uses. On a dating site I created I added an extra column to the table and was able to display an online icon next to users that were logged in, the same in search results to show users doing searches what users were currently online. with a bit of imagination it could be used for a few more scenarios.

Also, with a membership feature, when a user logs in you can update the session table to show that they are a member rather than a guest and if the user logs out you can remove the session from the table. Its best when a user logs out but stays on the site that you generate them a new session for security purposes. This is a bit more than what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have the browser leave an HTTP connection open to your server for some unused resource (like /usercounter) that your server never responds to. Then you count the number of open connections. You can have the request send a cookie associated with the user's session so you can know if the connections are all unique users.  This solution is very difficult and you will likely not find any ready-to-go solutions for implementing this.

The solution above will get a count of users who have javascript enabled.  For other users, you would have to have some sort of guesstimate of how long a user would be around and update that timer on each page load.